# Adding other user to ACL in Parse

Tags: acl, parse-platform

When the current user creates an object I want to add another user (e.g. admin) some rights to that object. The question is how to get the admin user's object while signed in as another user?

In the following code the `setWriteAccess()` is never called for any user other than admin.

```
var user = Parse.User.current();
var acl = new Parse.ACL(user);
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.get('ADMIN_USER_ID', {
    success: function(admin) {
        acl.setWriteAccess(admin, true);
    }
});
```

As I understand Parse does not allow any access to other user's object by default.

Answer (score 0):

The *correct* way would be to assign the admin user a role called 'Admin', and add write access for that role to the ACL. You may also be able to find the javascript equivalent to "objectWithoutDataWithObjectId:" to create a parse object with the ID assign to the role.